# Convert minutes to Hours:Minutes in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, data-conversion

Morning Team,

I have an Oracle SQL script that is calculating from creation of an event and how many minutes old compared to the systimestamp.
I need to convert the minutes, which are coming out as 120 for 2 hour for example, into Hours:Minutes version, i.e. 2:00

I'm struggling with that part and would like to ask if someone could help? My current code for the calculation is:

```
(ROUND(((cast(systimestamp as date) - cast(n.createdttm as date)))*1440,0)) "Minutes old",
```

I'm sure it's something simple but with all my fiddling I am not able to get it.

Thank you

Comment: As you're casting to date, is `createdttm` also a timestamp? If so why are you casting - why not just subtract the two timestamp and work with the interval result? (And if it's a date then there's really no point casting; and you could use sysdate instead of systimestamp). Also what do you want to happen if the difference exceeds 24 hours - still only show hours, or include the number of days?

Comment: Hi Alex, `createdttm`  is in the same format at `systimestamp` i.e. 18-AUG-22 07.26.30.869000000. I'm also not really sure how to apply the `INTERVAL`to the results as per @Thorsten Kettner below. If the time exceeds 24 hours I would need the format of DD:HH:MM but it should not exceed that far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `createdttm` is a timestamp, so you can just subtract:

```
systimestamp - createdtm
```

... to get an interval value like `+000000000 02:00:00.00000`. You can't format that directly, but you can either extract the various elements and concatenate those back together, or treat it as a string and cut out the bits you want.

If you only want the time part and it will always be less than a day you can just do:

```
substr(systimestamp - createdtm, 12, 5)

02:00
```

But if it can go over 24 hours then you probably want the day part too, which you could still get just with substr (and maybe replace to change the space to another colon) if you know it can never be more than 2 days:

```
substr(systimestamp - createdtm, 10, 7)

0 02:00
```

That's unlikely to be a safe assumption though, so instead you could extract the number of days and concatenate that:

```
extract(day from (systimestamp - createdtm)) || ':' || substr(systimestamp - createdtm, 12, 5)

0:02:00
```

You *could* only show the number of days if it's non-zero, but that would probably be quite confusing to who/whatever is looking at the results; but if you really wanted to:

```
case when extract(day from (systimestamp - createdtm)) > 0
     then extract(day from (systimestamp - createdtm)) || ':'
end || substr(systimestamp - createdtm, 12, 5)

02:00
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1c6e0e4caaf959784d481686baa7bf3b) with a few sample values.

One thing to note is this effectively truncates the seconds off the time; your original attempt included `round()`, but that might not have been what you meant.

Comment: Thank you @Alex Poole, this works perfectly! really appreciate your patience and explanation

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `INTERVAL` form the minutes.

```
select numtodsinterval(120, 'minute') from dual
```

Or create a datetime from the minutes and convert its time part to a string of hours and minutes.

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate) + interval '1' minute * 120, 'hh24:mi') from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to convert minutes to hours and minutes.
If x is the number of minutes (such as 350):

```
TO_CHAR ( FLOOR (x / 60)) || ':'
                  || TO_CHAR ( MOD (x, 60)
                         , 'FM00'
                     )
```

If u want to convert hours and minutes to minutes.

```
SELECT  (TRUNC (x) * 60) + 
    ( (MOD (x, 1)
    * 100 
    ) 
FROM    dual;
```

where x is a NUMBER. If you have a sting, s, instead, use TO_NUMBER (s) in place of x.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function      minutes_to_hhmm(p_minutes in number) return varchar2
as
begin
case when p_minutes is null then return null ;
     when p_minutes is not null then
return
to_char(trunc(p_minutes/60))||':'||lpad(to_char(trunc(mod(p_minutes,60))),2, '0');
end case;
end minutes_naar_hhmm;
```